# How to restore Oracle 10G database from backup

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, recovery

I have an Oracle 10G database.
I ran following script to take the backup of the database.

```
alter tablespace EMP2010 begin backup;
host copy G:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\ORCL\EMP2010.DBF G:\orabackup\database\
alter tablespace EMP2010 end backup;

alter tablespace PAYROLL2010 begin backup;
host copy G:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\ORCL\PAYROLL2010.DBF G:\orabackup\database\
alter tablespace PAYROLL2010 end backup;

host copy G:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO2010_1.LOG G:\orabackup\database\
host copy G:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO2010_2.LOG G:\orabackup\database\
host copy G:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO2010_2.LOG G:\orabackup\database\

alter system switch logfile;
host sleep 60
host copy G:/oracle/product/10.2.0/oradata/orcl/arch* G:\orabackup\database\/
alter database backup controlfile to 'G:\orabackup\database\/controlbackup.bac';
```

The backup generated .dbf, .log and .bac files.
Now I want to restore the database from the above taken backup files.
I do not want to use RMAN.

I have come to know that using following command I can restore the .dbf files into tablespace:

```
imp transport_tablespace=Y tablespace=(Ts Name) 
    file='location of dump file C:\user.dmp'
    datafiles=('location of dbf file')
```

In above imp command, I do not understand which file to supply against "location of .dmp file" as my backup has not generated any .dmp file.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

IMP is the mechanism for importing database objects previously exported using EXP.  This does not apply in your case.

What you need to do is manually restore the database.  To do this use `RECOVER DATABASE`.  There is lots of things relating to this topic, far more than can be covered here, so the best thing for you to do is [read the online documentation](http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10734/osrecov.htm#1009638).

Answer (score 0):

You can use IMP with transportable tablespaces to move datafiles but you need an EXP as well.

Your EMP2010.DBF contains a bunch of data for the contents of tables/indexes.
However your SYSTEM.DBF contains the metadata (eg what columns are in the table, which tables are in which tablespace). Without the metadata, the contents of EMP2010.DBF are unintelligible.

An EXP can export the metadata (with ROWS=N) into a DMP file.

You don't need to worry about moving redo logs, archived redo logs or control files for a transportable tablespaces copy.